# Problem with IP address as positional argument

Tags: c, sockets

I want to enter an IP address and a PORT number as positional arguments.
Like this:

```
./client 127.0.0.1 12345
```

They pass, I check that they are correct (I solved this with two functions, whose arguments I passed as char *), and then I try to pass the IP address and PORT number to two variables. sin_port accepts the PORT number as a value, but s_addr doesn't accept the IP address (in principle).
Like this:

```c
int ret;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]); //inet_addr accepts char*
servaddr.sin_port = htons (atoi(argv[2]));

// then

ret = connect (connSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
```

And because of connect() the terminal don't do anything.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for answers!

---

Edit:

Here is the code of my client module:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

// ./clientTest (távoli IP) (port)

#define MAX_BUFFER 1024
// #define MY_PORT_NUM 62324 /* This can be changed to suit the need and should be same in server and client */

int valid_digit(char *str)
{
    while (*str) {
        if (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9')
            ++str;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
} // ha a string csak számokat tartalmaz, akkor a visszatérési érték TRUE, egyébként FALSE


int valid_ip(char *ip)
{
    int i, num, dots = 0;
    char *ptr;

    if (ip == NULL)
        return 0;

    ptr = strtok(ip, ".");

    if (ptr == NULL)
        return 0;

    while (ptr) {

        if (!valid_digit(ptr))
            return 0;

        num = atoi(ptr);

        if (num >= 0 && num <= 255) {
            ptr = strtok(NULL, ".");
            if (ptr != NULL)
                ++dots;
        } else
            return 0;
    }

    if (dots != 3)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int valid_port(char *port)
{

    int num;

    if (port == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (!valid_digit(port))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    num = atoi(port);

    if (num < 0 || num > 65535)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if (argc > 1)
  {
    if (!valid_ip(argv[1]))
    {
      printf("HIBA: A megadott IP cím hibás!\n");
      return 0;
    }
    if (!valid_port(argv[2]))
    {
      printf("HIBA: A megadott PORT szám hibás!\n");
      return 0;
    }
  }



  int connSock, in, i, ret, flags;

  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  struct sctp_status status;

  char buffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1];
  int datalen = 0;

  connSock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);

  if (connSock == -1)
  {
      printf("Socket creation failed\n");
      perror("socket()");
      exit(1);
  }

  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons (atoi(argv[2]));
  if (inet_aton(argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) != 1)
  {
    fputs("Invalid IP address", stderr);
    return 1;
  }

  if ((connect(connSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr))) == -1)
  {
    perror("ERROR connecting");
    close(connSock);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ret = connect(connSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
  }

  if (ret == -1)
  {
      printf("Connection failed\n");
      perror("connect()");
      close(connSock);
      exit(1);
  }

  printf("Enter data to send: ");
  fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stdin);

  buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;
  datalen = strlen(buffer);

  ret = sctp_sendmsg (connSock, (void *) buffer, (size_t) datalen,
        NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  if(ret == -1 )
  {
    printf("Error in sctp_sendmsg\n");
    perror("sctp_sendmsg()");
  }
  else
      printf("Successfully sent %d bytes data to server\n", ret);

  close (connSock);

  return 0;
}
```

I drew a conslusion from information what Wireshark provided: it seems like the IP address argument doesn't pass correctly to the program.
From Wireshark:

```
09 39.287070587 192.168.0.104 0.0.0.127 SCTP 82 INIT 3
```

Where 0.0.0.127 is the destination IP.

If you want my server code, then tell me.

Comment: It most certainly does do something. The connect call either succeeds or fails. With this code how can you possibly tell?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: run it through `strace` and inspect arguments and return codes there

Comment: From strace: `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP) = 3`
`connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(62324), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.127")}, 16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `valid_ip()` functions alters `argv[1]` so that "127.0.0.1" becomes "127":

```
    ptr = strtok(ip, ".");
```

Use a prototype with `const` modifiers (e.g. `int valid_port(char const *port)`) and implement it so that it compiles without errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `sin_family`, i.e.:

```c
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
```

Also, use `inet_aton` instead of `inet_addr` as it allows proper error handling:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s HOST PORT\n", argv [0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int connSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (connSock == -1) {
        perror ("Error creating TCP socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if(inet_aton(argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) != 1) {
        fputs ("Invalid IP address", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    servaddr.sin_port = htons (atoi(argv[2]));

    if (connect (connSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr)) == -1) {
        perror ("Error connecting");
        close (connSock);
        return 1;
    }

    puts ("Connection successful.");

    close (connSock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My code right now:
`bzero((void *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));`
`servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;`
`if(inet_aton(argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) != 1) {`
`{`
`fputs ("Invalid IP address", stderr);`
`return 1;`
`}`
`servaddr.sin_port = htons (atoi(argv[2]));`
`ret = connect (connSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));`

But still nothing.
Sorry for bad formatting.

Comment: Check the return value of `connect`, print an error message using `errno`. Wait until the connect timeout elapses and check the error. Use wireshark to see whether the initial connection packets are sent. Use `nc` (netcat) to check whether your computer can initiate that connection at all (firewalls etc).

Comment: 1. errno gave Connection timeout() 2. From Wireshark: `109 39.287070587 192.168.0.104 0.0.0.127 SCTP 82 INIT` 3. When I'm using `servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");` it works well.

Comment: I updated the code to a complete example including `inet_aton`, which works for me...

Comment: I checked arguments with strace and they are correct, but when it writes `Connection refused` and it gives an Error 37. And in order to when I merge my code (above) with your code, in strace the IP argument is messed up again.

Comment: Why do you call `connect` twice? `inet_aton` should set the byte order correctly; are you using a Big Endian system? Maybe the C library is configured incorrectly?

Comment: I'm using openSUSE TumbleWeed 64-bit, so I think it's little endian. How to check if configuration is incorrect? Sorry, I'm a student programmer.

Comment: So amd64? That's little endian. Weird, then I don't know what's wrong.